# How to synthesize 3‐cyclopentylpropanal from (chloromethyl)cyclopentane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, carbonyl-compounds

[image: 3‐cyclopentylpropanal from (chloromethyl)cyclopentane]

I am not sure on how to start, but I think of these two possible ways:

1. Reacting the starting material with Grignard reagent and then oxidise the product with PCC to produce the aldehyde;
2. Hydrolysis the starting material to produce alcohol and then react the alcohol with PCC to form aldehyde.

But these two ways didn't give the desired product.

Answer (score 4):

3 Steps:

Step 1 - react the starting material with the preformed anion of ethyl cyanoacetate (NaOEt/EtOH should do this comfortably)

Step 2 - mild base hydrolysis of the product (NaOH/EtOH) followed by acidification to remove the ethyl ester group.

Step 3 - Dibal-H reduction of the nitrile to aldehyde [1](http://commonorganicchemistry.com/Rxn_Pages/Nitrile_to_Aldehyde/Nitrile_to_Aldehyde_Index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed with the following idea:

React the given starting material with Mg turnings in ether to form Grignard reagent. Now react this with sodium 2-chloro ethanoate. Now add lithium aluminium hydride (LAH) to this and then oxidise it to aldehyde using PCC.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you have a reference for the reaction of the Grignard with 2-Chloroethanoic acid?

Comment: @Waylander my organic chem teacher once gave the reaction...will look for a citable reference and share once I get it :)

Comment: Please correct me if there's any mistake in it

Comment: Grignard reagents will surely react with carboxylic acids, just not in the way you think. It's just an acid-base reaction:$$\ce{RMgBr + R'COOH -> RH + R'COOMgBr}$$

Comment: @orthocresol I agree, that's why I would like to see a reference. I don't think this will work with the acid or the sodium salt

Comment: @Waylander, my comment certainly wasn't directed at you :-) I agree that enolate + alkyl chloride is the way rather than alkyl Grignard + alpha-carbonyl electrophile.

Comment: @Waylander I couldn't find any reference online so I am certainly wrong on this one. Thank you for pointing out the mistake in my answer.

Comment: @Orthocresol Thank you for those suggestions. Now should I delete my answer as someone who may have not read the comments may be misled by my answer

Comment: Grignard with epoxide may work better.